# How to delete an item in the array and keeping the order the same?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I'm working on this project that allows me to add and delete elements In the array. When I delete elements in the array there would be a zero in that space and the code should shift the values after the deleted value to take its place. For Example: In the Array {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. I choose to delete 3. My output should be {1, 2, 4, 5}. Instead my output is {1, 2, 5, 4}. Could someone help me figure out why it would do that? And how to rectify it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntBag2 {
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 20;
    private static int[] bag;
    private int capacity;

    public IntBag2() {
        bag = new int[INITIAL_SIZE];
    }

    public IntBag2(int capacity) {
        bag = new int[capacity];
    }

    public boolean add(int item) {
        if (capacity == bag.length)
            return false;

        bag[capacity++] = item;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(int item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            if (bag[i] == item) {
                bag[i] = bag[--capacity];
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "Bag: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            result += bag[i] + " ";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        IntBag2 intBag = new IntBag2();
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. Add an Item to the Array");
            System.out.println("2. Delete an item in the Array");
            System.out.println("3. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Add an Item to the Array");
                System.out.println(intBag.add(input.nextInt()));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Delete Item of Array");
                System.out.println(intBag.delete(input.nextInt()));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("toString");
                System.out.println(intBag.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to look at the source of `java.util.ArrayList` - particularly the `remove()` method.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use an Array List the project is about Partially Filled Arrays.

Comment: Yes, but you can read the source code to see how things are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler implementation of `delete` is possible allowing to "delete" *all* entries in the array equal to the given `item` and shift the remaining ones to the front efficiently:

```java
public boolean delete(int item) {
    System.out.println("deleting " + item); // for debug purposes
    int oldCapacity = capacity;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < oldCapacity; i++) {
        if (bag[i] != item) {
            bag[j++] = bag[i];
        } else {
            capacity--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("new capacity = " + capacity); // for debug

    // or use Arrays.fill(bag, capacity, oldCapacity, -1); instead of the loop
    for (int i = capacity; i < oldCapacity; i++) {
        bag[i] = -1; // mark free entries with -1 in the tail
    }

    return oldCapacity == capacity;
}
```

Also, method `toString` should use `StringBuilder` if multiple concatenation are used in loop, or for brevity the following method `print` using utility methods from `Arrays` may be implemented:

```java
public void print() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(bag, capacity)));
}
```

Test:

```java
IntBag ibag = new IntBag(10);
ibag.add(1);
ibag.add(3);
ibag.add(3);
ibag.add(2);
ibag.add(1);
ibag.print();
ibag.delete(2);
ibag.print();
ibag.delete(1);
ibag.print();
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 3, 2, 1]
deleting 2
new capacity = 4
[1, 3, 3, 1]
deleting 1
new capacity = 2
[3, 3]
```

---

**Update**

"Deletion" of only the first entry without creation of new array may be implemented as follows:

- skip all elements until `item` is detected or end of `bag` is reached
- if `item` found, shift the remaining elements by 1, write -1 to the last element, return `true`
- return `false` otherwise

```java
public boolean deleteFirst(int item) {
    System.out.println("deleting first " + item);
    int id = 0;
    while (id < capacity && bag[id] != item) id++;
    if (id < capacity && bag[id] == item) {
        while (++id < capacity) {
            bag[id - 1] = bag[id];
        }
        bag[--capacity] = -1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```java
IntBag ibag = new IntBag(10);
ibag.add(1); ibag.add(3); ibag.add(1); ibag.add(2); ibag.add(1);
ibag.print();
ibag.deleteFirst(1); ibag.print();
ibag.deleteFirst(1); ibag.print();
ibag.deleteFirst(1); ibag.print();
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 1, 2, 1]
deleting first 1
[3, 1, 2, 1]
deleting first 1
[3, 2, 1]
deleting first 1
[3, 2]
```

Comment: I need the delete method to only delete an item the first time it appears not every time. I was asking for this method because I need to implement another method that deletes all which you have provided me. Now I need the method to delete an item the first time it appears nothing more.

Comment: @EzequielSoler, you may check the update

Answer (score 0):

With the line `bag[i] = bag[--capacity];` you are basically getting the last item in your array and place it in the location of the deleted one.

Given that you are using `int[]` (instead of `Integer[]`) we can't assign an index of the array as `null`. The best we can do is assigning it `-1` or create a new array.

I decided to create a new array from scratch. The following will do the trick.

```java
public class IntBag2 {
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 20;
    private static int[] bag;
    private int capacity;

    public IntBag2() {
        bag = new int[INITIAL_SIZE];
    }

    public IntBag2(int capacity) {
        bag = new int[capacity];
    }

    public boolean add(int item) {
        if (capacity == bag.length)
            return false;

        bag[capacity++] = item;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(int item) {
        int[] newBag = new int[capacity];
        int newCapacity = capacity;
        boolean deleted = false;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            if (bag[i] == item && !deleted) {
                deleted = true;
                newCapacity = capacity - 1;
            } else {
                newBag[j++] = bag[i];
            }
        }

        bag = newBag;
        capacity = newCapacity;
        return deleted;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "Bag: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            result += bag[i] + " ";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can I change it to get the next item in the array and place it in the location of the deleted one?

Comment: Can you use `ArrayUtils` from Apache Commons?

Comment: I've added a possible solution to my answer. If it is not ok for or use case just let me know.

Comment: The order is fixed but the output is now {1, 2, 4, 5, -1} If I were to remove 3 from the array {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Comment: How would I use ArrayUtils?

Comment: Is your project using maven or gradle? If so you would need to include `commons-lang3` dependency and then you simply need to use `remove` method as `ArrayUtils.remove(bag, item)`.

Comment: Never mind my professor would not approve of this since it's not something I ever learned in class. For this method, I have to use what I was taught that being for loops.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Is creating a new array ok? I guess there are no other option.

Comment: Yes, that works. I've used the Arrays.copyOf for some of my other methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237937/discussion-between-ezequiel-soler-and-joao-dias).

Comment: @EzequielSoler I've updated my answer, please check it ;)